# Spacewalk, Kickstart, Cobbler, PXE, Dnsmasq

Tags: pxe-boot, kickstart, dnsmasq, cobbler, spacewalk

I have installed a Spacewalk server. One of the final features I am trying to configure is Kickstart.  I cannot seem to find any definitive documentation on how to set this up in a "real environment".  We already have a DHCP server, I would like to use dnsmasq with PXE.

Since the documentation is scarce regarding Spacewalk, I have looked towards cobbler documentation.

Spacewalk 2.0 is bundled with Cobbler 2.0.11. A couple of sites suggest installing cobbler-loaders for additional features.

**Environment**

CentOS 6.4 (64-bit) / Spacewalk 2.0

**Questions**

1. As I couldn't find in the "official documentation", should cobbler-loaders be installed?
2. Is dnsmasq already installed as part of cobbler/Spacewalk or should it be installed using it's own package?
3. Since cobbler seems to work independently to Spacewalk, should I be able to do a yum install cobbler for the latest version 2.4.3, or would that not be a wise course of action?
4. Since I may have someone's attention, would there be a guide that I may have missed or someone has put together that would help?

Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but why Spacewalk? I thought that was depreciated, everyone uses Puppet or Chef these days I thought?

Comment: @Chopper3 I'd personally agree not to use Spacewalk but Puppet/Chef is not a replacement for it. Maybe Razor?

Comment: Spacewalk is not depreciated, although have recently been made aware of [Katello](http://ww.katellog.org/faq/). The decision for Spacewalk was made before me, I need to make it work.  Maybe look into Katello, which looks promising, however, at the moment Spacewalk is the path I must take.

Comment: Have you looked at Foreman? It has kickstart integration.

Answer (score -1):

Upstream [`cobbler`](http://www.cobblerd.org/manuals/2.4.0/2_-_Cobbler_Quickstart_Guide.html) is at version 2.4.0. I can see no point in using something older.

The link is both to the current online docs of the product and a quickstart guide to having a working environment.

With regards to kickstart, the [online Red Hat official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) covers the topic in great detail.

Comment: I too don't see the point in using something older, however, I am not certain that doing a `yum install -y cobbler` will "break" the Spacewalk server. Currently when I do a `yum list cobbler` it does not show as installed, however, as available.

As for the Kickstart documentation, I've read through that many times and nowhere are my questions addressed in it.

Comment: On our spacewalk 2.1 server, both cobbler20 and cobbler2 (and cobbler-loaders) is installed.  It isn't called just cobbler, probably because it is an older version.  I wouldn't install the newer version, just to be safe. I'm also not sure a newer version would give you anything else that you need.